# Multi-port usb-c adapter HDMI port for second display does not work on linux laptop

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb

### Summary

I have a Satechi usb-c multi-port adapter. I currently use it to connect my mouse and keyboard through the usb-port, but I want to use the HDMI port for my secondary screen. I currently use the screen via the normal HDMI port but I want to use the adapter.

The adapter itself works fine for both usb and HDMI for two other laptops, a Windows 10 and a Macbook.

Does it have to do with my graphics drivers? Do I need to install something?

I've looked at dozens of different threads but none has pointed to a solution that seemed to work for me, or use the same adapter. But maybe I'm missing something!

Thanks :)

### Setup

OS: Ubuntu 18.04.5

Kernel: 4.15.0-122-generic

Hardware: HP 14-bp078no

GPU: Intel HD Graphics 620

### Additional Information

`lsusb` with the adapter plugged in:

```
Bus 002 Device 010: ID 05e3:0749 Genesys Logic, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 011: ID 0bda:8153 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 009: ID 0bda:0411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 008: ID 2109:0817 VIA Labs, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:b009 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 015: ID 04d8:0b29 Microchip Technology, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 014: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 013: ID 0424:2137 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 012: ID 0bda:5411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 011: ID 2109:0102 VIA Labs, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 2109:2817 VIA Labs, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04f2:b5db Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`lsusb` *without* the adapter plugged in:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:b009 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04f2:b5db Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`xrandr` with the HDMI cable plugged in the adapter:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 308mm x 173mm
   1920x1080     60.01*+  60.01    59.97    59.96    59.93    40.00  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

If you look at the user guide which I downloaded [here](https://support.hp.com/id-en/product/hp-14-bp000-laptop-pc/15551432/model/21909037/manuals), it seems to me the laptop is supposed to be able to handle HDMI over usb-c.
[image: from the user guide]

Answer (score 0):

The image provided of the port description does read *(select products only)* so that's one indication that it's at least possible there's no video output on the USB-C port.  Looking at the user manual there is no mention of the possibility to use the USB-C port for video out, only the HDMI port is mentioned.  I'm quite confident that the reason the HDMI output on your USB-C mini-dock is not working on this one computer is because the USB-C port does not support video output.

If you want to use the same USB-C mini-dock on all three computers and have the HDMI port work then you can get a dock with DisplayLink.  DisplayLink is a series of USB to video adapter chips which a number of manufacturers will use in their docks.  This is more complex than splitting off a DisplayPort signal from a USB-C port that supports it so it costs more.  Because USB doesn't have as much bandwidth as DisplayPort the video will not be as good.

There's ways to solve this but it's going to be cheap *or* easy, not both.  You found the cheap solution.  The easy solution is a dock with DisplayLink in it.  If there's another solution then perhaps someone else can provide it.